# analogue of the c typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING and PUBLIC_OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION on vba

Tags: vba, winapi

Trying to get HKEY name using NtQueryObject

```
Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260
 
Private Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT As Long = &H80000000
Private Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER As Long = &H80000001
Private Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE As Long = &H80000002
Private Const HKEY_USERS As Long = &H80000003
Private Const HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA As Long = &H80000004
Private Const HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG As Long = &H80000005
 
Private Const KEY_READ As Long = &H20019
 
Private Const ERROR_SUCCESS As Long = 0
 
Private Type FILETIME
    dwLowDateTime As Long
    dwHighDateTime As Long
End Type
Private Declare PtrSafe Function RegOpenKeyEx Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegOpenKeyExA" ( _
    ByVal hKey As Long, _
    ByVal pSubKey As String, _
    ByVal ulOptions As Long, _
    ByVal samDesired As Long, _
    phkResult As Long) As Long

Private Enum OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS
    ObjectBasicInformation      ' // 0
    ObjectNameInformation       ' // 1
    ObjectTypeInformation       ' // 2
    ObjectAllTypesInformation   ' // 3
    ObjectHandleInformation     ' // 4
End Enum

Type UNICODE_STRING
    Name As String
    Length As LongPtr
    MaximumLength As LongPtr
End Type

Type PUBLIC_OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION
    Name As UNICODE_STRING
End Type


Private Declare PtrSafe Function NtQueryObject Lib "Ntdll.dll" _
        (ByVal Handle As Long, _
        ByVal ObjectInformationClass As OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS, _
        ByRef ObjectInformation As Any, _
        ByVal ObjectInformationLength As Long, _
        ByRef ReturnLength As Long) As Long
        


Public Enum NTSTATUS
    Successful = 0
End Enum

Function findreg()

If RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_USERS, ".DEFAULT\Console", 0, KEY_READ, hKey) <> ERROR_SUCCESS Then Exit Function

Dim buffer_STRUCT As PUBLIC_OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION
Dim lngVarAddress As LongPtr
lngVarAddress = VarPtr(buffer_STRUCT)
cbBuffer = 80
ObjectNameStatus = NtQueryObject(ByVal hKey, ObjectNameInformation, lngVarAddress, cbBuffer, ReturnLength)

end function
```

I get this line
buffer_STRUCT.Name.Name = "\REGISTRY\USER.DEFAULT\Console???a?A??????PQ?????????????????????????????"
how to create a structure correctly?

Comment: Sounds like you are not taking the `UNICODE_STRING.Length` into account when handling the `UNICODE_STRING.Name` data. A `UNICODE_STRING` is not guaranteed to be null-terminated, and even if it is, the `Length` does not include the terminator. Also, your declaration of `UNICODE_STRING` does not look right, either. The `Name` field should be the last field, not the first field. And the `Length` and `MaximumLength` fields should be 16bit `Integer`s , not pointer-sized `LongPtr`s

Comment: Also, your declaration of UNICODE_STRING does not look right, either. I read the description of UNICODE_STRING and thought the same but if Name field is not first then UNICODE_STRING.Name = <Application-defined or object-defined error> and if Length and MaximumLength are not LongPtr then UNICODE_STRING.Name = = "\REGISTRY\U?E?.DEFAULT\Cons?l????a?A??????PQ?????????????????????????????"

Comment: Considering that `PUBLIC_OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION` is undocumented, I can't be sure what its contents really are. The only thing I can find on it is [this 3rd party definition](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FType%20independed%2FOBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION.html). But [`UNICODE_STRING` is documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntdef/ns-ntdef-_unicode_string) (and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/subauth/ns-subauth-unicode_string)) by Microsoft, and what is documented is accurate.